# Is it possible to find Facebook mutual friends using the API?

Tags: facebook

I was wanting to find out if it is possible using the Facebook API or Open Graph and two users ID to out put there mutual friends?

As i have managed to do this but it only lists the mutual friends that are 'playing your game' not the whole list.

bellow is the function i have created:

```
function getMutualFriends($facebook, $uid1, $uid2,$amount=3){
    $random_ids     = array();
    try {
        $param  =   array(
                    'method'  => 'friends.getMutualFriends',
                    'source_uid'    => $uid1,
                    'target_uid'  => $uid2,
                    'callback'=> ''
                );
        $mutualFriends   =   $facebook->api($param);
        if(count($mutualFriends) < $amount){
            $amount = count($mutualFriends);
        }
        $random = pickrandom($mutualFriends,$amount);

        for($i=0; $i<$amount; $i++){
            $random_ids[] = get_name($random[$i]);
        }
        $output = implode(",\n", $random_ids);
        print_r($output);
    //  print_r($mutualFriends);

    }
    catch(Exception $o) {
        print_r($o);
    }
   // return 'None';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that you are using ([friends.getMutualFriends](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getMutualFriends/)) is of the REST API which is deprecated:

> Please note: We are in the process of deprecating the REST API. We
>   have added a Graph API equivalent of this call which is the
>   'mutualfriends' connection of the User object. An example call to this
>   is `/PROFILE_ID/mutualfriends/FRIEND_ID` which will return the mutual
>   friends that PROFILE_ID has with FRIEND_ID.

All you need to know is right there, just use the [mutualfriends connection of the User object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#mutualfriends).

Also, if you want to compare two users who installed your app then you can just get the friends of both users (`USER_ID/friends`) and compare yourself.